# Using SPServices to get user's "My Links" via jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, spservices

I am trying to get the current user's list of "My Links" using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) & jQuery

I am new to SPServices and I found [this page](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices) about how to get values from the user's profile and specifically the supported operation `GetUserLinks`, however, I am not sure how to format this request.

Here is my lame attempt:

```
var UserName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
   fieldName: "Name",
   debug: false
});
var UserLinks = $().SPServices.UserProfileService.GetUserLinks(UserName)
```

I appreciate any help constructing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetUserLinks",
  accountName:"username",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    console.log(xData)
  }
});
```

Your syntax for the SPGetCurrentUser is correct but that doesn't on my Sharepoint... I see, at least, two other options to find the current user :

1. With [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.whoami) (a JavaScript API) :

   ```
   $SP().whoami({url:"http://my.si.te/subdir/"}, function(people) {
     console.log(people["AccountName"]);
   });
   ```
2. Or you can change your masterpage to always have the details regarding the current user into your code. Have a look at this [English blog post](http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/displaying-user-information-on-a-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010/) or this [French blog post](http://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2012/08/21/recuperer-les-details-dun-utilisateur-dans-une-masterpage-sharepoint/). Then it's easy to get the username from the HTML directly.

Comment: AymKdn, this is great information. Thank you for responding. I will try your solution later today and let you know if it works.

Would you recommend SharepointPlus over SPServices or do you recommend using both?

Comment: I think SharepointPlus is easier to use because of its syntax, but I'm not objective because I've created it ^^, but just do what you think is the most relevant for you.